# How to show horizontal lines in Edit Text Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to show lined edit text in my android notepad app, I have created linededittext class in Activity. But I am not able to set us a view in xml file. It is giving android.view.inflateException, Binary xml file line 17 inflate class"

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.Add_Task.LinedEditText
android:id="@+id/note"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:padding="5dip"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
android:gravity="top"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:capitalize="sentences"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity where I am using LinedEditText class:

```
public class Add_Task extends Activity{

private EditText description;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_task);
    description = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.note);
}
```

}

LinedEditText Activity:

```
class LinedEditText extends EditText {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

// we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public void init(){
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF668800); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //int count = getLineCount();

    int height = getHeight();
    int line_height = getLineHeight();

    int count = height / line_height;

    if (getLineCount() > count)
        count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
  } 
}
```

Please suggest. thanks...

Comment: Anybody there...Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You don't use view as the tagname.  You use the fully qualified classname

Comment: <view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" have issue in this line.

Comment: Sorry, part of my post got killed by stack overflow.  Use <com.example.MyClass> as the tag, not <view>

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity you can call that customized EditText with your custom name as follows..

```
public class Add_Task extends Activity{

LinedEditText description;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_task);
    description = (LinedEditText)findViewById(R.id.note);
}
}
```

So that it'll work

Comment: <com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.LinedEditText  It is giving error in this line, not working

Comment: i am using  <com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.LinedEditText but I am implementing it in Add_task activity, so is there any need to use Add_task in above line???

Comment: Oh its working now..I simply used EditText in activity not LinedEditText..Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Dear bro From LinedEditText Class remove constructor's third parameter